# Number of permutations of BANANA if (1) the two Ns are separated and (2) the three As are all separated

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

One way to do (1) is subtract all permutations of BAXAA (where X = NN) from all the permutations of BANANA: $\frac{6!}{2!3!} - \frac{5!}{3!}.$

I was wondering if it is possible to solve (1) by letting X = NBN, Y = NAN, counting the number of permutations of BAYA and XAAA and taking their sum to get $\frac{4!}{3!} + 3(\frac{4!}{2!})$ where the coefficient $3$ is to account for three different A's.

The reason I am unsure about the second method for (1) is that I can't seem to get (2) right. Here I let X = AA, Y = AAA, count the number of permutations of BXNNA and BYNN and subtract their sum from the total number of permutations of BANANA which is $\frac{6!}{2!3!} - (\frac{4!}{2!} + \frac{5!}{2!}) = -12.$

My questions.

Is the second method for (1) correct? Why do I keep getting $-12$ in the solution of (2)? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is the second method for (1) Correct?*

For (1), your first method is correct, your second is correct for the wrong reasons.  Notice that you can have the $N$'s be separated by more than one letter.  You do not count $NBAAAN$ for example in your count.  On the other hand you inflated the number by multiplying by three when you shouldn't have... the $A$'s are all identical, so we don't care *which* of the $A$'s was sandwiched between the $N$'s since they result in the same outcomes.

If you were to approach directly, you'd have to take into account not only the case with $NAN$ and $NBN$, but also $NAAN, NABN, NBAN, NAAAN, NAABN,\dots$ and is entirely too much work.

> *Why do I keep getting $-12$ in the solution of (2)?*

Some of the arrangements of $BXNNA$ and $BYNN$ are the same, for example $BXANN$, $BAXNN$ and $BYNN$ are all referring to $BAAANN$ but you subtracted it from the count three times when you should have only subtracted it once.

> *How do I fix it?*

For a correct solution to part (2), first pick an arrangement of $XXXAAA$ such that no $A$'s are next to one another and then afterwards replace the $X$'s by an arrangement of $BNN$

- Arranging $XXXAAA$ such that no two $A$'s are adjacent:

You may do this more formally using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) (*which you should do for more complicated problems*) or you may simply brute force count the number of valid arrangements by hand.  They are:

$AXAXAX, AXAXXA, AXXAXA, XAXAXA$

- Replacing the $X$'s in whichever of the selected arrangements from the previous step by an arrangement of $BB$

Pick which of the three locations currently occupied by an $X$ is to be taken by the $B$.  The remaining locations are then used by the $N$'s.

Multiplying, there are then $4\cdot 3=12$ valid arrangements.

Comment: Yes, I see it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @4chan my pleasure.  Thank you as well for doing as requested by showing your work and explaining what you tried and where you got stuck.  +1 for a well written question.